# Remove All classes From Divs in form

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 <dialog class="qq-prompt-dialog-selector">
     <div class="qq-dialog-message-selector"></div>
        <input type="text">
        <div class="qq-dialog-buttons">
        <button type="button" class="qq-cancel-button-selector">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" class="qq-ok-button-selector">Ok</button>
     </div>
 </dialog>
```

I want remove all class in dialog ? what need i do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change an element's class with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/how-to-change-an-elements-class-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `$('dialog *').removeAttr('class');`

```js
$('dialog *').removeAttr('class');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dialog class="qq-prompt-dialog-selector">
     <div class="qq-dialog-message-selector"></div>
        <input type="text">
        <div class="qq-dialog-buttons">
        <button type="button" class="qq-cancel-button-selector">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" class="qq-ok-button-selector">Ok</button>
     </div>
 </dialog>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```js
$('dialog').removeClass();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dialog class="qq-prompt-dialog-selector">
     <div class="qq-dialog-message-selector"></div>
        <input type="text">
        <div class="qq-dialog-buttons">
        <button t

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

ype="button" class="qq-cancel-button-selector">Cancel
            Ok

Answer (score 0):

See the attachments.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEEPq.png)

$('div').removeClass();

Comment: Please provide more details. And read how to write a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hi Naresh, I didn't get your comment why should I read about the link can you please tell me.